# Правильная реализация long-polling

Tags: php, клиент-сервер

Наткнулся на [код сервера](https://github.com/panique/php-long-polling/blob/master/server/server.php), предназначение которого обеспечение ajax + long polling запросы к серверу.

В нем есть момент: запускается бесконечный цикл с `sleep(1)`, который ждет пока что-то изменится, и посылает запрос обратно, завершая свою работу.

Затем наткнулся на статью человека, который отказался от вебсокетов по аргументированным причинам в сторону long polling сначала на php, но затем ушел, так сказать, "на компиляцию".

Но там же есть [такой вот](https://habrahabr.ru/post/275671/#comment_8747687) (это та статья) интересный комментарий, который предлагает реализацию какого-то общего цикла...
Благодаря которому всё бы прекрасно работало для проекта автора статьи.

Я как-то натыкался на то, что каждый запрос в long polling запускает на апаче новый процесс и он будет висеть на каждое соединение столько, сколько нужно, занимая оперативную память. И что при количестве подключений чуть больше, чем низкое, сервак уже ложится.  Чего бы мне не хотелось с моим.

Так вот, как сделать этот "общий цикл"? Что это такое в принципе?
Как правильно составить серверный код на обработку long pooling?

Я реализую сервис, которым пользоваться будут, наверно, человек 300 одновременно... Честно говоря, я вообще никогда виртуальный хостинг не имел и это первый проект "в свет", так что мне сложно сказать о нагрузке)
Но очень переживаю уж за неё, не хочу написать код, который совершенно бесполезен окажется из-за постоянных дропов сервера.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61646/discussion-on-question-by-vostoksisters---long-polling).